# Surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n \geq 5$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I know that a surface mapped to a 3-space gives a generic surface with singularity set consists of double points, triple points and branch points (Ofcourse, the singularity set may be empty, such a case gives an embedded surface, i.e standard surface).

A surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$ might be embedded or immersed with singularity set contains only isolated crossing points. 
I don't have a picture of surfaces in 5 dimension and higher. 
I have a feeling that any surface in $\mathbb{R}^m$, $m\geq 6$ is a standard surface. This is because the crossing information change is allowed. 
Could you please help me to get the picture of the surfaces in all dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

A generic surface in 5-space has no singularities. Note, however, that your claims about 3-space and 4-space are false --- you can map a sphere to 3-space so that all points go to the origin $(x, y, z) \mapsto (0,0,0)$ or to a line segment $(x, y, z) \mapsto (0, 0, z)$, or many other possibilities. Only if you assume that the mapping is generic can you make the claims you did (which is why my answer is for generic surfaces).

Comment: I see, a generic surface in 5-space has no singularities, this is because a 2-manifold has empty intersection with another 2-manifold in 5-space. Thank you.

Comment: Well, how about crossing changes in 5-space? I know for a classical knot (circle in 3-space), the crossing change move is an isotpy move if the circle is embedded in 4-space or higher, so we can always unknot the knot in higher dimensions. Now if the surface is embedded in 5-space, can we get similar result as for classical knot, so that only surfaces in 4-space are interesting.

Comment: There are indeed knotted surfaces in 5-space. I think you perhaps need to read a good book about the Whitney embedding theorem and understand a bit about how dimension and knotted-ness interact. Then, when you think you understand it, look at Haefliger's paper on knotted $4k-1$ --spheres in $6k$ space.

Comment: Fine, thank you so much Hughes.